Rational vector in integer matrix Kernel
Let $A \in \mathbb{N}^{n \times q}$ for $q < n$ natural numbers. Is there a polynomial algorithm to assert if exists $\begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 &... &\lambda_n\end{bmatrix}^T \in \mathbb{Q}^n$ with $\lambda_i \neq 0$ such that
$$
\begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 &... &\lambda_n\end{bmatrix} \cdot A = 0_{1\times q}
$$ ?
